# Read Values of specific array at specific XML node with PHP

Tags: php, xml, tree-traversal

Hello I am trying to list tour name in the 6 node of filter object. Formated xml image is also attached.

This is my loop.

```
foreach($results->filters->filter[6] as $key=>$tours){

    foreach($tours as $tour_name){
        echo $tour_name->tour->tour_name;
    }
}
```

XML-Response

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the text.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `foreach($results->filters->filter->[6] as $key=>$tours){` note the -> between filter and [6]

Answer (score 1):

You need to go one level deeper on your foreach loop

```
foreach($results->filters->filter[6]->tour as $key=>$tours){

    foreach($tours as $tour){
        echo $tour->tour_name;
    }
}
```

Or as PatrickQ suggested below do it all in one loop

```
foreach($results->filters->filter[6]->tour as $tours){
    echo $tours->tour_name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riggs. I tried but strange thing is, filter[6] has 44 tour node. It iterate through all 44 nodes but it does not print tour_name, or id or code.

Comment: I don't think you need the inner loop. Keeping all else the same, I think it could be replaced by `$tours->tour_name`.